# Understanding the flow of this Python code

Tags: python, late-binding

I saw this code on the internet, and I don't know how it works.

```py
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x : i * x for i in range(4)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

Here are some questions:

1. What is the output of the list which is returned by the multipliers function?
2. What is meant by `m(2)` here? Since it didn't mentioned what is m before anywhere in the code. But still the code works without any error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: 2. ‘m’ is mentioned in the list comprehension.

Comment: Huh. This code has surprising behavior to me. I would expect that multipliers() would return a list of four different lambdas, which would return different values when evaluated with x = 2. But instead it prints [6, 6, 6, 6]. What am I not following about how these lambdas are created?

Answer (score 4):

`multipliers` function which returns a list of functions (more exactly some anonymous functions aka lambdas) :

```py
multipliers()

# the return of multipliers function
[<function multipliers.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x11243c048>, <function multipliers.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x11243c0d0>, <function multipliers.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x11243c158>, <function multipliers.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x11243c1e0>]
```

`[m(2) for m in multipliers()]` list comprehension in which you iterate and call each function from the list returned by `multipliers` .

The catch is that python closures are late-binding , which means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function it is called (`lambda x : i * x for i in range(4)`)

That is why for your case the printed list is `[6, 6, 6, 6]` because the functions from the list (returned by `multipliers`) are actually looking something like this `lambda x : 3 * x` and when you are iterating and calling each lambda in your list comprehension `[m(2) for m in multipliers()]` you are actually calling more or less the same function

If you want to "fix" the behaviour of `multipliers` function you can do something like this:

```py
def fix_multipliers():
    return [ lambda x, i=i: i*x for i in range(4)]
```

Afterwards you will see the "expected" behaviours:

`print([m(2) for m in fix_multipliers()])`
`[0, 2, 4, 6]`

PS : Closure is a function object that remembers values in enclosing scope even if they are not present in memory aka extend the scope of the inner function.

Comment: Is it possible to force Python to bind the variables earlier, in such a way that this would actually print [0, 2, 4, 6]? ETA: Oh, neat!

Comment: The above capture does so

Answer (score 1):

The output of the above code will be [6, 6, 6, 6] (not [0, 2, 4, 6]).

The reason for this is that Python’s closures are [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked at the time the inner function is called. So, when any of the functions returned by `multipliers()` are called, the value of `i` is looked up in the surrounding scope at that time. By then, regardless of which of the returned functions is called, the `for` loop has completed and `i` is left with its final value of 3. Therefore, every returned function multiplies the value it is passed by 3, so since a value of 2 is passed in the above code, they all return a value of 6 (i.e., 3 x 2).

in other terms lambda returns the value of i when called. The lambda is called after the loop has finished, so i is 3 by the time it's called.

Comment: That's nice and all, but doesn't answer the question(s).

Comment: so basically lambda returns the value of i when called. The lambda is called after the loop has finished, so i is 3 by the time it's called.

Comment: And that addresses neither of the two questions asked.